# Problem with progress upload bar using XMLHttpRequest in Django

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue with a progress upload bar in Django when the site is deployed to Heroku, when I click on the upload button the progress bar shows up at 10% then doesn't change or count up to 100%, when the upload is finished, it redirects as instructed in my views.py , the function runs fine locally, but after deploying to heroku it doesn't work. I think it may be something to do with the deployed url using 'https', but not sure and how to fix it? appreciate any help.

custom.js

```
function progressBar() {
    progressBox.classList.remove('not-visible')
    cancelBox.classList.remove('not-visible') 

        const upload_data = input.files[0]
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(upload_data)
        // console.log(upload_data);
    
    const fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf[0].value)
    fd.append('track', upload_data)

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: fd,
        beforeSend: function(){

        },
        xhr: function(){
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', e=>{
                // console.log(e);
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    const percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                    // console.log(percent);
                    progressBox.innerHTML = `<h5 style="text-align:center;">${percent.toFixed(1)}%</h5>
                                            <div class="progress" style="height: 30px;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: ${percent}%" 
                                            aria-valuenow="${percent}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                            </div>`
                }
            })
            cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                xhr.abort()
                progressBox.innerHTML=""
                cancelBox.classList.add('not-visible')
                window.location.reload();
            })
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(response){
            // console.log(response);
            uploadForm.reset()
            cancelBox.classList.add('not-visible')
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    })

}
```

Comment: I don't think http vs https would cause such an oddity - though, I have been known to get these things completely wrong - have you tried different browsers to see if the problem is across all browsers - or have you tried just using XMLHttpRequest yourself without jquery getting it's hands on the request

Comment: I've just tried the function in chrome and it works fine , it seems safari and firefox are not responding ?

Comment: not responding? I thought you said the upload finishes, just the progress doesn't show properly